# HDMI (M) to VGA (F) vs HDMI (F) to VGA (M) - Why does one type need USB power?

Tags: conversion, vga, hdmi

Hopefully this is the right thread, if not, please let me know the correct thread to post this.

Been looking for another HDMI to VGA converter, and noticed this anomaly.

Converters that are [HDMI (M) to VGA (F)](http://www.banggood.com/1080P-HDMI-Male-To-VGA-Female-Adapter-Video-Converter-Cable-p-937626.html), are just a converter, no additional audio or USB power requirement. However, converters that are [HDMI (F) to VGA (M)](http://www.banggood.com/VGA-TO-HDMI-HDTV-Video-Converter-Line-Adapter-p-1055246.html?rmmds=search), will require USB power and often have additional audio support.

Why is that? Why does one type of conversion require USB power while the other type does not? Is this just because the products are made this way? Or is there a electronic design reason behind this?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an important distinction between those two devices. The first converts *from* HDMI *to* VGA, whereas the second converts *from* VGA *to* HDMI. They are not bidirectional converters.

HDMI provides a low power +5V supply through the cable which is designed to power the DDC channel (display identifier) in the screen so that it can be identified even when the display is off. This supply is used in the HDMI to VGA converter to power the electronics that do the conversion.

VGA originally did **not** provide any power supply to the cable, only RGB, H-Sync, V-Sync and ID lines. Later on a 5V line was added to power the DDC channel (which replaced the ID lines), however because it was added later not all VGA ports provide the new signalling (though all modern ones probably will). As a result the designer of the signal conversion circuitry cannot assume there to be a source of power available through the VGA cable and so needs a secondary cable to supply power. Micro-USB is used simply because USB is a readily available 5V power supply.

Comment: Also ADC takes much more power than DAC?

Comment: @user3528438 not necessarily. Without knowing what is inside I can't say. The HDMI to VGA adapter I have also has a USB port to provide additional power if the HDMI port can't supply enough when running at higher resolutions, though I have never used that as my laptop output can handle it without the extra supply connected.